# Copy to Clipboard in DataGridView KeyDown picks up MessageBox text

Tags: winforms, datagridview, clipboard

I have a `DataGridView` in which I'm capturing `CTRL+C` in the `KeyDown` event, and generating some specific clipboard text.

The function is simple, and confirms the action completed with a MessageBox.

```
private void ActionCopyToClipboard()
{
    Clipboard.Clear();
    Clipboard.SetText("Test");

    MessageBox.Show("Copied to clipboard."); 
}
```

For some reason, after this function, the clipboard contents contain the text of the message box-

```
    ---------------------------

    ---------------------------
    Copied to clipboard.
    ---------------------------
    OK   
    ---------------------------
```

Rather than the value specified in `Clipboard.SetText()`.  If I remove the MessageBox call, everything works fine.

Why would the MessageBox content get picked up?

Answer (score 1):

The clue presented itself at the end of my question-

I'd not noticed this before but the Windows `MessageBox` apparently also processes `CTRL+C` on the `KeyUp` event internally.

My `KeyDown` event was setting the text fine, and displaying the MessageBox.  The release of the `CTRL+C` was then generating a `KeyUp` event which the MessageBox intercepted, and replaced my text with.

Switching my event handler to use `KeyUp` solved the problem.